# Elastic APM elastic.apm.ignore_exceptions does not work

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm, observability

I want to use elastic.apm.ignore_exceptions setting to ignore temporary logs from APM Agent when queue in APM Server is full or when APM Server is not working so it receive 503 error.
So exceptions from **co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler**

Based on doc:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/config-core.html
I added elastic.apm.ignore_exceptions in elasticapm.properties, then as linux ENV, then as JAVA_OPT (`-Delastic.apm.ignore_exceptions=co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler`) but nothing changed.

During startup my application I can see
`INFO  co.elastic.apm.agent.configuration.StartupInfo - ignore_exceptions: 'co.elastic.apm.agent.report.IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler' (source:`

but still I can se ERROR logs from IntakeV2ReportingEventHandler and still some functions in my app does not work because of that.

I use elastic-apm-java agent in 1.35 version

**Can someone explain how this setting should work?**

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you have to specify exceptions you want to ignore, not classes that throws them.